# How to create an AVD for Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Android 4.0 is now released. I have just updated my [ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html) plugin and downloaded the 4.0 SDK. But when I try to create an [AVD](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html) for Android 4.0, Eclipse tells me 'Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder'.

I found `d:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-14` missing the 'images' folder which other versions have. This folder may have 'userdata.img' that create an AVD should have.

Where should I to get 'userdata.img', and how do I create an AVD for Android 4.0?

Answer (score 441, accepted):

I just did the same. If you look in the "Android SDK Manager" in the "Android 4.0 (API 14)" section you'll see a few packages. One of these is named "ARM EABI v7a System Image".

This is what you need to download in order to create an Android 4.0 virtual device:

[image: The Android SDK download system]

Comment: That's reslove my problem, thank you @Matthew. The new image folder is now at D:\android\android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-14.

Comment: I'm just going to add a additional point that I ran into. Even if you download the AVD Manager that is external to eclipse and says you have it installed, you have to go into eclipse with the AVD Plugin and re-install it as well. Have to 2 it twice. I ran into this error when going through the setup steps even though I had the ARM EABI installed external from eclipse.

Comment: My issue was the same as @haju my external SDK had the ARM v7a System image installed but the one in Eclipse did not. Thanks @haju!

Comment: Every time I update or install the Android SDK, there is some problem.  You would think that Google would have figured out how to iron out the install process by now.  Then again, it's not like installing MS's or Apple's tools is that much better.

Comment: damn!  i skipped only that package.

Comment: hey, i skipped that package too

Comment: How many MBs of data do I need to download to test one single hello world application?

Comment: I have had the same problem as haju. I have Android SDK in `c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\ ` and the Eclipse has it's own Android SDK set to `c:\Users\Martin\android-sdks\ `. I dont get this, but it doesnt matter. I strictly followed instructions from google's android site and got this. Not a big deal, but annoying. I lost about two hours for this.

Comment: I had all this installed, still didn't work, I had to select an option for the CPU/ABI and then it installed.

Answer (score 17):

Another solution, for those of us without an internet connection to our development machine is:

Create a folder called `system-images` in the top level of your SDK directory (next to `platforms` and `tools`). Create subdirs `android-14` and `android-15` (as applicable).
Extract the complete `armeabi-v7a` folder to these directory; sysimg_armv7a-15_r01.zip (from, e.g. [google's repository](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sysimg_armv7a-15_r01.zip)) goes to `android-15`, sysimg_armv7a-14_r02.zip to `android-14`.

I've not tried this procedure offline, I finally relented and used my broadband allowance at home, but these are the target locations for these large sysimg's, for future reference.

I've tried creating the `image` subdirs where they were absent in 14 and 15 but while this allowed the AVD to create an image (for 15 but not 14) it hadn't shown the Android logo after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 9):

This site [Android Create AVD](http://www.idimmu.net/2013/03/23/android-create-avd/) shows you how to install the latest version of the Android SDK and AVD version 4 in Eclipse with video and screenshots if you're still stuck?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem but using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) rather than [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). I already had the ARM EABI installed, but I still got the error.

For IntelliJ IDEA, it appears you also have to create an AVB first before running the emulator, so to do this you must just go into Android SDK Manager and create a new AVB. This should solve your problem... Please make sure you have followed the above answer to include the ARM before following these steps.

Comment: Same error using IntelliJ on Mac OSX.  1. Confirm ARM EABI is installed  2. Tools->Android->AVD Manager-> Create new AVD  3. Run->Edit Configurations->Android Application or Android Tests -> Emulator (radio button) -> Select your newly created AVD

Answer (score 6):

You can also get this problem if you have your Android SDK version controlled. You get a slightly different error:

> Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI .svn to copy into the AVD folder.

For some reason, the Android Virtual Device (AVD) manager believes the `.svn` folder is specifying an [application binary interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (ABI). It looks for `userdata.img` within the `.svn` folder and can't find it, so it fails.

I used the shell extension found in the responses for the Stack Overflow question *[Removing .svn files from all directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301203/removing-svn-files-from-all-directories)* to remove all `.svn` folders recursively from the `android-sdk` folder. After this, the AVD manager was able to create an AVD successfully. I have yet to figure out how to get the SDK to play nicely with [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion).

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the system image and still get this error, it might be that the Android SDK manager did not put the files in the right folder for the AVD manager. See [an answer to Stack Overflow question *How to create an AVD for Android 4.0.3? (Unable to find a 'userdata.img')*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699536/734151).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for creating AVD in Android Studio.

1. First click on AVD button on your Android Studio top bar.

[image: image 1]

2. In this window click on <kbd>Create Virtual Device</kbd>

[image: image 2]

3. Now you will choose hardware profile for AVD and click Next.

[image: image 3]

4. Choose Android Api Version you want in your AVD. Download if no api exist. Click next.

[image: image 4]

5. This is now window for customizing some AVD feature like camera, network, memory and ram size etc. Just keep default and click Finish.

[image: image 5]

6. You AVD is ready, now click on AVD button in Android Studio (same like 1st step). Then you will able to see created AVD in list. Click on Play button on your AVD.

[image: image 6]

7. Your AVD will start soon.

[image: image 7]