# AVD Creation of Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) for windows

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Android 4.0 is released now.  Where can i get that ADT Plugin for android 4.0. And, also where can i get the Android 4.0's SDK.

I'm using Eclipse for developing the android. I just googling about this but i got answer for [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817044/how-to-create-a-avd-for-android-4-0) Where can i get these things for Eclipse using Windows OS. Anyone guid me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo are using the Eclipse so ,For 4.0 SDK trace Window>AndroidSdkManager > AvailablePackages >then Select the Platform 14 . it will update your Sdk . 
After updating your Sdk you need to update the ADT Plugin .For that trace Help >CheckForUpdate . then select the ADT for platform 14.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can i get that ADT Plugin for android 4.0.And, also where can i get the Android 4.0's SDK.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

After following these steps, launch your SDK Manager and you will see Android 4.0 (API 14). Hit Install 5 packages.

[image]

Comment: I didn't find any android 4.0's repository in my SDK and AVD manager. Will i use new sdk?

Comment: If you had an older version of the SDK manager (you had one before ICS came out) a popup window with available packages to install should pop. Go to android repository and select API 14 revision 1.

Comment: If you can't see it you are probably using the wrong SDK, yes, use the new SDK, [like shown in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=OZ65gIf9KkY#!)

Comment: @Jong : yes, you're right. Now, am downloading API 14 revision 1

Answer (score 1):

Once you download ADT plugin inside the Eclipse, you can download any SDK platform.

After updating or installating ADT 14.0, you will get this SDK Manager (**Just check the below snap, i have already installed SDK 4.0**)

[image]

### Update:

For updating ADT plugin, you have to check in eclipse: **`Help -> Check for updates`**

Answer (score 1):

it is very easy, instead of downloading update your adt in eclipse, do the following,

Open eclipse and goto Help-->Install New Software  in that you can see Work with text box

in that select

update site: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/   that's all you can see developer tools version 14.0 then install that and restart eclipse after install completed.  After restarted open sdk manager there you can see android 4.0 then select and update.