# Android - Can't create new v4.0 AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've made a fresh eclipse reinstall + Android SDK v4.0. I am trying to create a new 4.0 AVD and getting this error:
[2011-10-21 11:36:38 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.

Reading [How to create an AVD for Android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817044/how-to-create-a-avd-for-android-4-0), I checked SDK manager and I have 'ARM EABI v7a System Image' installed. to be on the save side I un-installed and reinstalled it.

I also copied 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-13\images' into 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-14'

Still getting the same error. I have no problems creating 2.1 AVD.

Note: I'm running Win XP

Issue fixed itself after restarting the PC.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817044/how-to-create-a-avd-for-android-4-0

Comment: Read my question again. I already tried that and also linked the same article hoping I won't get directed there.

Comment: Try run in administrator mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after restarting my machine.

Answer (score 3):

THis worked
http://learn2program.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/beginning-android-4-with-intellij-idea-unable-to-find-a-userdata-img-file-to-copy-into-the-avd-folder/ 
Apparently the location of the image file changed recently.
Basically, in eclipse, go to run/debugconfig/android app/new config/target/automatic(yes, reclick it)/manage and then follow the sdk manager reinstall methods.
I'm in the middle of it now and this report is somewhat from memory since the download is occurring as I type this.  OK, it worked to get the AVD in.  Hello World is next ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the Android SDK provided by google and once again via Eclipse you install the SDK while configuring ADT plugin. System wont recognize the first installation.

1. There for as "user1123966" said you can solve it
2. OR by going to Windows-> preferences -> android-> and change the SDK location to the First Installation.

I would recommend you to go for first option and uninstall the first installation.

Answer (score 0):

update `ARM EABI v.. System` Image  by Android SDK Manager

Answer (score 0):

The location of userdata.img changed in more recent versions of the Android SDK and Eclipse hasn't been adjusted to accomodate it yet. Here's what worked for me:

Within your Android SDK folder, take all the files from system-images/android-15 (or whatever API version you have) and move them to platforms/android-15. For me, this meant moving two folders: armeabi-v7a and x86. I was able to make an AVD fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

i was recently facing the same problem and tried all solutions here, but none was working for me.

my fault was, that i didn't made a choice in the CPU/ABI section, after creating a new devie in the avd-manager. (Guess I started with a bad tutorial, since this field was left open there  too...)

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't get it to work after the above comments, you should try to update your ADT version (to at least 20). After that I was able to install ARM EABI v.. System Image and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid "unable to find a "userdata.img file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder" error when creating Android 4.0.x AVD, you should make sure the "ARM EABI v7a System Image" is installed in all the "Android 4.0.x" sections in SDK manager. and don't forget restart AVD manager after all packages are installed completely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here's my context and how I solved it.

When I was opening my **Android SDK Manager** through **Start** > **All Programs** > **Android SDK Tools** > SDK Manager, *I was able to see* the **ARM EABI v7a System Image** package and *it was actually installed*.

When I was opening my Android SDK Manager **through Eclipse**, *I wasn't even able to see the ARM EABI v7a System Image package*.

I figured out after that the SDK Manager I was accessing *through the Start menu* was located at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk** while the SDK Manager I was accessing *through Eclipse* was located in **C:\Users\$(CURRENT_USER)\android-sdks**

So I *removed* the whole C:\Users\$(CURRENT_USER)\android-sdks folder and reconfigured Eclipse to use C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk folder : **Window** > **Preferences** > **Android** then browsed SDK Location field to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk**.

This is one of the many reasons you could have this error so just adding my personal case and solution.

Cheers.