# AVD creating error for android development

Tags: android

Am a beginner in android just setting up my development environment...

I have eclipse and I have downloaded the ADT plugin for eclipse plus the Android SDK.

Am trying to create a new AVD but am getting an error as follows:

[2012-03-06 20:20:04 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.

How can i resolve this.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817044/how-to-create-a-avd-for-android-4-0) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also install the "ARM EABI v7a System Image", it can be found in the "Android 4.0.3" folder in the SDK manager.