# How to create an AVD for Android 4.0.3? (Unable to find a 'userdata.img')

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create my first AVD for Android 4.0.3 following [the tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html), but I'm getting the error message:

> [2012-05-09 10:46:29 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.

My attempts to solve:

- I was trying with the Android 4.0, now I updated to the 4.0.3 and the problem is the same.
- I reinstalled the Eclipse plugin twice with 4.0 and twice with 4.0.3, and the behavior doesn't change.
- I downloaded the Eclipse for Java again, to another folder, and installed the plugin. The behavior is the same.

The file `<sdk>/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a/userdata.img` exists, it's a 4mb file, read-only.

**Related question**: [How to create an AVD for Android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817044/how-to-create-an-avd-for-android-4-0) - the answer didn't worked here.

I'm running Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I know it is a stupid mistake to make and you would have thought of it, but are you sure that you had selected "ARM EABI v7a System Image" under **"Android 4.0.3 (API 15)"** for downloading?

Comment: In theory the linked answer should fix it. Have you installed both ARM EABI System Images? There are different ones for 4.0 and 4.0.3. Maybe you installed the one for 4.0 and tried to create a 4.0.3 AVD by accident - which doesn't work?

Comment: @Rajesh yes, I selected everything twice (with Android 4.0 and 4.0.3)

Comment: @alextsc I uninstalled all 4.0 itens before installing the 4.0.3. Now I have only 4.0.3, and I'm trying to create an AVD for 4.0.3 (there's no option for the 4.0).

Comment: The Images are specific for the SDK versions. You can check whether the images have been downloaded correctly by going to <ANDROID_SDK_PATH>/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a and checking for existence of userdata.img

Comment: @Rajesh the file is there. A 4mb file, read-only.

Comment: Assuming that you start your AVD Manager from Eclipse, can you check the _Window->Preferences->Android->SDK Location_ in Eclipse refers to the actual SDK location that has the system images?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you have all of the latest files installed.  Go to the SDK manager in Eclipse (WINDOW/SDK Manager).  Make sure all of the files show "installed".

Comment: Hey, it's showing as not installed... But why the sdk manager from `<sdk>/tools` is showing as "installed"? It should be the same sdk manager... :/

Comment: I'm installing now the image from the Eclipse's Android SDK (that I thought was the same in tools folder), hope that will solve...

Comment: Do i need to download all packages?

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem when trying to setup an emulator for Android 2.3.3 (API 10).

I had two platforms installed in my SDK: API 10 and 17. I noticed that the `userdata.img` files for these platforms were located as below:

```
system-images/
  android-17/
    x86/
      userdata.img
  android-10/
    x86/
      images/
        x86/
          userdata.img
```

So as you can see, the emulator images for the `android-10` platform were probably not put in the right folder.

Anyway, in short: if you are in the same situation, just move the contents of the `android-[version]/x86/images/x86/` folder to the `android-[version]/x86/` folder. It worked for me.

Obviously, if you are trying to launch an ARM image, do the same thing with the `armeabi` folder instead of the `x86` folder.

Comment: I can get rid of the userdata.img is missing message when I move the files inside android-10/x86/images/x86 to android-10/x86 (not /images). Also the emulator would start and tell me that it uses haxm. But then when the emulator UI launches, it gets stuck. I know this is not the original problem of this thread, but do you have any  more input on how you made your API Level 10 AVD using X86 acceleration work? Thanks

Comment: (Sorry for hijacking the OP's question - but for the sake of completeness to my question above): My problem was that the AVD Manager starts emulator64-x86. Using emulator-x86 instead solved the problem for me. More here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/gwcLeOTfxD4

Answer (score 2):

i think you also have to download ARM EABI v7a System Image under Android 4.1

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an installation guide to get Android SDK and Eclipse working together. There are a couple of pitfalls which you may run into especially on Windows with regards to Firewalls. Here it is:

http://testigniter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/eclipse-with-android-sdk-installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK manager (run as admin) --> Android 4.1 (API 16) --> ARM EABI v7a system image. Install this.