# Android Virtual Device not Found

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adb, android-virtual-device

I installed Android SDK and Eclipse and everything. When I ran my first Android app I got the following error:

SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.

How can I solve this?
[image]

Comment: read these posts..

this one
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086630/unable-to-find-a-userdata-img-file-for-abi-armeabi

and this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517555/how-to-create-an-avd-for-android-4-0-3-unable-to-find-a-userdata-img

Comment: have you downloaded it from the AVD plug in or from the android tool on the /tools? try re-installing from eclipse AVD plug-in.

Comment: I used the Eclipse ADT Plugin. I do not see any devices under manager.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in this blog:
http://tech.thecoolblogs.com/2012/01/unable-to-find-userdataimg-file-for-abi.html