# Android API 15, can't create a new AVD

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I'm started today using Android SDK.
I have installed the Android SDK with all his packages for 4.0.3 (API15).
and YES I HAVE install the ARM EBAI v7a System Image !

i have also installed the ADT for my Eclipse (Indigo) and checked that all is updated.
but when i tried to create a new AVD i got this error:
"Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder."

i just don't know what the problem is i already tried all the fixes that i found here and on the web but i can't make it work...

my details:

OS: WinXP SP3

JDK: 1.7.0_03 (Orcale's)

SDK: Android 4.0.3 API 15

BTW sorry about my poor English.

Comment: search before asking a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817044/how-to-create-an-avd-for-android-4-0

Answer (score 0):

> JDK: 1.7.0_03 (Orcale's)

JDK 7 is [not supported](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) by the android tools.
Try it with a JDK 6 installation and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Recently had this problem, may not be the fix for you, but the issue I had was on the 'Create New AVD' page. Under 'CPU/ABI' make sure there is a selection - usually ARM (armeabi-v7a).

Mine is blank so I have to set it myself, then the error goes away.