# AVD not getting created

Tags: android

[image]I have a strange problem. I installed Eclipse juno on my system and even installed the SDK manager. But when am trying to run the app no AVD is showing up. When am trying to configure the AVD by going to Windows-> AVD Manager and by clicking on the New button a dailog is opening up AVD name, memory options and internal memory. But for whatever values i give, the ok button is disabled and hence am not able to create a AVD to launch the application.

I tried succeding by modifying this block in androidManifest file.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: @varevarao: I have added the screen shots and have mentioned what all i tried. plz help. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You notice how it says beside `CPU/ABI` that there's no system image for the current target? That's the reason for the `Ok` option being washed out. Try updating your SDK if you want to use this AVD, and install all available updates. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7817100/1782481) for what that'll look like.

Otherwise just lower the SDK level (the `target` option) and try various levels till you find one for which it works (that is, for which you have the system image installed).

Answer (score 1):

Your system seems to be **missing the system image** required to create the AVD.

Go to **Eclipse -> Window -> Android SDK Manager**

In your desired section of API level, select **ARM EABI v7a System Image** and download it.

Comment: I tried doing the same. But its giving error stating Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
download at 31663459 (27%)
Download interrupted: Connection reset
Done. Nothing was installed. Why so? How can I launch an AVD??

Comment: You are probably having problems with you internet connection, as stated by `Connection reset`. Try again later when you have a more stable internet connection, as you cannot start the AVD without downloading the ARM system system or the Intel x86 image. But Intel x86 image is not available for API 17 yet, so you have two choices. Get on a more stable internet connection and try to download ARM EABI system image or move to a lower API version for which you have all the required components installed in your system.