# Can't create AVD in eclipse or android studio,

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When I want to create a new AVD, there are no "ok" button to let me click on it after I fill in all the specification.

This happen in android studio and eclipse with ADT.

Please help me, I am new to android development.

Comment: snapshot or any error message ?

Comment: have you downloaded the system image(iso)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an AVD for Android 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817044/how-to-create-an-avd-for-android-4-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto

> Window>Android sdk Manager>

and choose a version of android and select

> SDK platform and system image ( arm or intel) its up to you.

now restart eclipse and open avd manager and now you can create Virtual devices

Hope this helps .. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select both target, cpu and skin. In the bottom left corner you will se a small red "x" together with text explaining what is missing.

Cheers!