# Not able to create AVD

Tags: android

The OK button of the AVD is not enabled after trying all sorts of things.

[image]

Comment: please don't link on external files, as they could change over time. post the code or, at least, embed the picture in your post.

Comment: Change the avd name to some other & make sure there is no space between words or at end.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817044/how-to-create-an-avd-for-android-4-0?rq=1)

Comment: stackoverflow did,nt allow me to post the image thats why.

Comment: I choose one of the device defination AVD_for_2_7_QVGA and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall the IDE and re-install it following the installation instructions such as specific downloads for certain Operating Systems ect. Worth a try if you have not done that yet.