# "emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration" Android Activity issue

Tags: android, android-activity

When I try to run the Hello, Android Activity, it says: **emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.**
And underneath that it says: **Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it.**

I'm stumped and would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

**This is what I have for the code:**

```
package my.helloandroid.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Hello, Android");
            setContentView(tv);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things which came to my mind.

1. Be sure to check if you have correct path to avd,  `Window->preferences`.
2. Press right mouse button on your project folder and use `android tools -> fix project`.
3. simply restart eclipse.

Comment: I tried all of those and nothing worked. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the manifest file or look here:

[Trouble getting Android emulator to run in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473553/trouble-getting-android-emulator-to-run-in-eclipse)