# Android app not running(emulator not starting from eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm learning how to make android apps from the docs, and I downloaded and unzipped the ant bundle

I opened `eclipse` and followed the tutorial, but when I click on the run button in the eclipse toolbar, nothing happens(no window pops up and neither does the avd start up).

I have made an `AVD`(through the avd manager icon in the same toolbar) , as the tutorial says.

I also started up the AVD with android 4.2.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, if that matters.

Please help me run my app, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you run the AVD normally? I mean without running your project?

Comment: @JaVAndroid ,yes i can run it

Comment: Nice, now see if any of the issues in the below question are relevent to your configurations: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2473553/867591

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i've got the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running the application whilst the AVD is up and running in the background?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you had to keep the emulator started while running.

Comment: The emulator should start when you launch, but doesn't always - I like to start it first, then deploy to it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the version of Android the app is built to support match that of the emulator.  Ie. if the emulator if configured to support 2.3.3, and your app is built to the 4.0 API then this might happen.

To run your app directly (taking Eclipse out of the equation).  You can issue the following command from the command line (this is a good test to perform).

```
adb install yourApkName.apk
```

Comment: No, the configuration is all right, and thanks for answering!