# No emulators work for my Windows 8

Tags: android, sdk

I'm new to programming and I've been having a lot of trouble with my Windows 8 computer downloading and running the android sdk. I finally got the android software to work. However, once I began to code my project and tried to test it, the emulator didn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could solve this problem? Thank you for your advice in advance!

Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google'
emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.
Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble getting Android emulator to run in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473553/trouble-getting-android-emulator-to-run-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473553/trouble-getting-android-emulator-to-run-in-eclipse), possible duplicate.

It might have something to do with your SDK HOME PATH environment variable.

You could also try using a third party emulator such as [Blue Stacks.](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

Answer (score 1):

check your ANDROID_SDK_HOME, it should point to your android sdk.

1. Start -> All Apps -> Control panel -> System -> 
   Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables.
2. Set ANDROID_SDK_HOME to your android-sdk path and restart your eclipse

Also check that the path does not have special characters.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried this and it still isn't working. Could there be another problem that I'm just not aware of?